# load xml from web with authentication PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, authentication

I am accessing a web API that returns XML. The website requires authentication.

I've gotten this first way to mostly work:

```
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
$webpage = $webclient.DownloadString($URL)
```

However, the xml is loaded as a string and not an actual XML document.

I've also tried this second way, but I get error 401, unauthorized, even after loading the first way successfully.

```
$HostRecord = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$HostRecord.Load($URL)
```

I need to either modify the first way to load to an object, or authenticate with the second way.

Comment: I just realized that I could type-cast the $webpage variable to be xml: [xml]$webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did with existing code:

```
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
[xml]$webpage = $webclient.DownloadString($URL)
```

I also understand that this might not be an issue if using the **Invoke-Restmethod** command instead of WebClient.